# How to post model with edited items in the grouped list?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model

I have the folllowing problem. I need edit item values in the grouped list and post model to server.

My model and view model:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string ParentName { get; set; }
    public string SubParentName { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}

public class MyViewModel
{
    public IList<MyObject> list;
}
```

And **simplified** (without html table grouping of the grouped items) implementation of view:

```
@model MyViewModel

@(using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post)))
{
    <table>
        <tbody>
            @foreach(var parentItems in Model.list.GroupBy(x => x.ParentName))
            {
                foreach(var subParents in parentItem.GroupBy(x => x.SubItemName))
                {
                    foreach (var item in subParents)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td><parentItems.FirstOrDefault().ParentName</td>
                            <td><subParents.FirstOrDefault().SubParentName</td>
                            <td>item.ItemName</td>
                            <td><input class="itemValue">**Editable value item.Value**</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <button type="submit">Save</button>
}
```

How do it?

**SOLVED**

```
@model MyViewModel

@(using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post)))
{
    <table>
        <tbody>
            @foreach(var parentItems in Model.list.GroupBy(x => x.ParentName))
            {
                @{ var counter = 0;}  
                foreach(var subParents in parentItem.GroupBy(x => x.SubItemName).Select(x => x.ToList()))
                {
                    for(int i = 0; i < subParents.Count(); i++, counter++)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.list[counter].ItemName)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.list[counter].ItemName)

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.list[counter].Value, new { myAttr = "myAttrValue"});
                            </td>                           
                        </tr>

                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Reports[counter].ParentName)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Reports[counter].SubParentName)
                    }
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <button type="submit">Save</button>
}
```

**Thank you all for your help :)**

Comment: I will suggest use `editortemplate ` for this

Comment: EditorFor binded to model. I want edit item from the model list.

Comment: You want edit item value ?

Comment: Yes this value MyObject.Value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting problem. Using a `foreach` loop wont work because the controls will not have the correct indexed `name` attribute for postback, and a single `for` loop wont allow your grouping unless you include conditional checks (e.g. test if the `ParentName` and `SubParentName` has changed from the previously rendered item and then render a new group heading or start a new table or whatever).

I suggest you create a view model to better represent the hierarchy and populate the view model on the controller

```
public class MyObject
{
  public string ParentName { get; set; }
  public string SubParentName { get; set; }
  public string ItemName { get; set; }
  public decimal Value { get; set; }
}

public class SubParentVM
{
  public string Name { get; set; } // assuming you want some kind of group heading
  public List<MyObject> Items { get; set; }
}

public class ParentVM
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public List<SubParentVM> Items { get; set; }
}
```

and the view

```
@model List<ParentVM>

for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
  ....
  for (int j = 0; j < Model[i].Items.Count; i++)
  {
    ....
    for (int k = 0; k < Model[i].Items[j].Count; i++)
    {
      <tr>
        <td>Model[i].Items[j].Items[k].ParentName</td>
        <td>Model[i].Items[j].Items[k].SubParentName</td>
        <td>Model[i].Items[j].Items[k].ItemName</td>
        <td>
          <@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.[i].Items[j].Items[k].Value)
          // Assuming you want other properties of MyObject to post back
          <@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.[i].Items[j].Items[k].ItemName)
          <@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.[i].Items[j].Items[k].SubParentName)
          <@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.[i].Items[j].Items[k].ParentName)
        </td>
      </tr>
    }
  }
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(List<ParentVM> items)
{
  ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Your controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Action([FromBody] values)
{
}
```

Your view code:

```
@(using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post)))
{
    <table>
        <tbody>
            @for(int i =0; i< Model.Count; i++)
            {
                 <tr>
                     <td>
                          @Html.DisplayFor(x=> x.ParentName)
                          @Html.HiddenFor(x=> x.ParentName)
                     </td>
                     <!-- same to all not editable fields -->
                     <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x=> x.Value)</td>
                 </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <button type="submit">Save</button>
}
```